# Linux redirect to login shell after login action

Tags: linux, redirection, login

I am using CentOS 6.4 operating system and everything was good until power-system crash :/ After successfully reboot I am normally asking for login/pass and after login shell redirects me to login shell again :/ Typing wrong password couses typical wrong-pass-communicate.

Trying to check file-system with LiveCD, everything is ok and placed on the right place.

No idee what could possibly go wrong :/ Any ideas?

EDIT:
I found out that my OS starts fluently on runlevel 5, but before failure it was set to run level 3. How can I list the diffrences between running processes on rl-3 and rl-5? On rl-5 all of my accounts work well.

SOLVED: 
I research a little bit about my issue and solution is:
http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/print.php?form=1&topic_id=16329&forum=44&order=ASC&start=0

Summary:

1. **vim /etc/pam.d/login**
2. change: **session required /lib/security/pam_limits.so** to **session required /lib64/security/pam_limits.so**
3. Save **:wq**
4. Reboot: **init 6**

Comment: Try to login as root and check if the `/home` partition has been successfully mounted

Comment: Is your `/home` encrypted?

Comment: None of file system directories is encrypted. Only possible way to log into system is change runlevel to single user mode.

Comment: Have you tried to login as root and checked if /home was mounted?

Answer (score 0):

It is just a guess, but because I had the same issue recently it may help. Because of the system crash, some SELinux labels might be damaged. To fix it:

1. Boot any live distribution and mount your disk
2. Edit `/etc/selinux/config` and change it to `SELINUX=permissive`
3. Reboot

If it works, use `restorecon` to fix the labels and re-enable SELinux.

Comment: I change this specified value to permissive but problem still exists. What can be interesting default value was set to "SELINUX=disabled".

One more thing which I did not mention before: when a try to log into single user mode it works. Then switch runlevel from 1 to 3 and try to log in but issue mentioned above occurs again.

Is it possible for example that GRUB config or sth like that was corrupted and now lock logging act? Or mayby unknown network issue blocks authorization process?

Will be grateful for any clues :)